# How do I handle multiple write functions from a socket.io room `emit` event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Going to provide some context first. Question is at the bottom.

**Background**

I'm making a browser based javascript game where users join a room and move tiles around. When the game is over, user data is sent to the server, where it needs to be merged with other user data, and then the resulting data gets sent back to each user to display the results of other players.

I am using an Express node server with socket.io (front end is react, fwiw)

**The issue at hand**

I have a json file for a game room, lets call it `1a2b.json`:

```json
{
  "roomID":"1a2b",
  "users":[
    {
      "name":"username",
      "id": 123,
      "tiles":[
        {"char":"I","x":false,"y":false,"r":false,"id":"1"},
        {"char":"X","x":false,"y":false,"r":false,"id":"2"}
      ]
    }
    {
      "name":"username2",
      "id": 456,
      "tiles":[
        {"char":"V","x":false,"y":false,"r":false,"id":"3"},
        {"char":"K","x":false,"y":false,"r":false,"id":"4"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When a game ends, players emit a socket event (`game-end`) that sends updated player `tiles` data. Something like:

```json
{
  "name":"username",
  "id": 123,
  "roomID":"1a2b",
  "tiles":[
    {"char":"I","x":21,"y":30,"r":"45deg","id":"1"},
    {"char":"X","x":50,"y":80,"r":false,"id":"2"}
  ]
}
```

On the server, when the `game-end` socket event is observed, I need to update the original `1a2b.json` file with the new data from each user, replacing the old `tiles` data for a player with the new `tiles` data.

All users will be emitting the event at the same time, which I assume will cause an `fs.writefile` error for some users.

**The Question**

How do I handle updating and writing the contents of `1a2b.json` when multiple update/write events are happening at the same time to the same file? And within a proposed solution, is there a way to tell when all write requests are complete, so I can emit data from the completed json file back to users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just running one Express instance, since Node is single-threaded, the server will only be able to process one write at a time anyway. So you will not encounter any errors.

The real solution would be to write to a database rather than a file.